# How to align second line of text to first line when using pseudo elements?

Tags: html, css

I have code like this:

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
header {
    font-size: 14px;
}
header h1 {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 4em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
header h1, header h1:before, header h1:after {
    font-weight: normal;
}
header h1:before, header h1:after {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    top: 0.05em;
}
header h1:before {
    content: "{";
}
header h1:after {
    content: "}";
}
header h1 a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
header a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
<header>
   <h1><a href="http://jcubic.pl/">Głównie JavaScript</a></h1>
</header>

<div style="width:320px">
<header>
   <h1><a href="http://jcubic.pl/">Głównie JavaScript</a></h1>
</header>
</div>
```

And when header is smaller (on small devices) the text is wrapped into two lines but the indent of second line is to aligned with first line. How can I make both lines of text align? Do I need to use media queries for that?

Comment: You want _J_ to appear below _G_?

Comment: @SalmanA yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a combination of negative `text-indent` and `margin` on `header h1` to achieve this.  It works because `text-indent` only affects the first line.

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
header {
    font-size: 14px;
}
header h1 {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 4em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-indent: -0.6em;
    margin-left: 0.7em;
}
header h1, header h1:before, header h1:after {
    font-weight: normal;
}
header h1:before, header h1:after {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    top: 0.05em;
}
header h1:before {
    content: "{";
}
header h1:after {
    content: "}";
}
header h1 a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
header a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
<header>
   <h1><a href="http://jcubic.pl/">Głównie JavaScript</a></h1>
</header>

<div style="width:320px">
<header>
   <h1><a href="http://jcubic.pl/">Głównie JavaScript</a></h1>
</header>
</div>
```